# Jquery changing color of table cell not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the color of a table row using jquery. I sort of have it working but sort of not.

Here is my function...

```
$("#tabHistoryBackups tr").each(function() {
    var startTimestampStr = $(this).find("td").eq(3).html();
    if (!isEmpty(startTimestampStr)){

        startTimestampStr = startTimestampStr.replace(/\-/g, " ");
        startTimestampStr = startTimestampStr.replace(/\./g, " ");
        startTimestampStr = startTimestampStr.split(" ");
        var startDateTimestamp = 
            new Date ( startTimestampStr[0], startTimestampStr[1]-1, startTimestampStr[2]);             

        var today = $.now();
        var todaysDt = new Date(today);
        todaysDt.setHours(0,0,0,0)       

        if (startDateTimestamp == todaysDt) {
            $(this).find("td").css('background-color','yellow');
        }           
    }

});
```

The problem I have is with ...

```
$(this).find("td").css('background-color','yellow');
```

If I take it outside the if statement then all my rows get highlighted. But as soon as it is inside my if statement as appears above the highlight no longer works.

Can someone please help me with what might be wrong here?

thanks

Comment: @Saksham why? startDateTimestampStr  is not a date object

Comment: Could you share us your HTML?

Comment: Startdatetepstampstr is not a date object. I cannot control that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check might be simpler with just a string comparison:

```
startTimestampStr = startTimestampStr.replace(/\./g, "-");

var now = $.now();
var nowStr = now.getMonth() + "-" +  now.getDate() + "-" +  now.getFullYear();

if (nowStr == startTimestampStr)
```